# React native redux, passing 2 reducers and 2 mapToProps functions

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to pass 2 functions that fetch some data to my component by using the connect function, 
as well of 2 stateToProps functions, 
it seems to doesnt work this way, I've only done one mapStateToProp function by now, now I need two...

Here's my code:

-- Component:

```
omponentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchNewsAction();
        this.props.getUser();
    }
....
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const playerInformartion = _.map(state.playerinformation, (val, uid) => {
        return {...val, uid };
    });
        return {playerInformartion};
};

const mapNewsToProps= ({ fetchNews }) => {
    const { news } = fetchNews;
    console.log(news);
    return  { news };
};

 export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapNewsToProps, { getUser, fetchNewsAction })(Lobby);
```

--Actions

```
export const fetchFixturesAction = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
    axios.get('https://rebrand.ly/rvlk53')
    .then(respone => { 
        console.log(respone.data)
        dispatch({type: FIXTURE_FETCH, payload: respone.data})
    }).catch(
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
            Alert.alert('בעיות חיבור, בבקשה תבדוק את חיבור האינטרנט')
        }
    );
    }
}


export const getUser = () => {
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
    return (dispatch) => {
     firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/playerinformation`)
     .on('value', snapshot => {
     dispatch({ type: GET_USER, payload: snapshot.val()})
    });
};
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mapStateToProps` [should return](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#return) object that contains part of state which will be passed as props to component. There is no way to pass two `mapStateToProps` to `connect`. And this is not required as you may do all mapping work in single `mapStateToProps` function.

Here is example for your case (not tested, use as hint)

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    // Prepare playerInformartion as you already did
    const playerInformartion = _.map(state.playerinformation, (val, uid) => {
        return {...val, uid };
    });

    // Now prepare news (this code is from mapNewsToProps function
    const { news } = state.fetchNews;
    console.log(news);

    // Now return one object containing playerInformartion and news

    return {playerInformartion, news};
};

// And use connect. Action to props map is correct, no need to change it
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getUser, fetchNewsAction })(Lobby);
```

And now you can access Redux state and actions from component

```
ComponentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchNewsAction();
        this.props.getUser();
        this.props.news;
        this.props.playerInformartion;
    }
```